# Dropdownlist in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I am trying to use simple dropdownlist in my edit form, where user can correct information, with help of dropdownlist.

So I use this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string zonesList)
{
   using (var dbVn = new userDbEntities())
   {
   ... 

     var zList = new List<string>();
     var zQuery = from d in dbVn.TimeZoneTables // take data for List from table
         select d.TimeZone;

     zoneList.AddRange(zQuery.Distinct());
     ViewBag.zonesList = new SelectList(zList);
   }
}
```

And in View I put this code:

```
Zones: @Html.DropDownList("zonesList")
```

My question is, how in View use this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("zonesList")

on this code

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TimeZoneId)
```

Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery or javascript as below:

```
   @Html.DropDownList("zonelist", new SelectList(ViewBag.zonesList,<value>,<text>),"Select Vendor/customer",new{ @class = "form-control",required = "required",@id="zone" })
```

Now want to change editor for value

```
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.TimezoneId,new{@id="time"})
```

Jquery code for above

```
<script  type="text/JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#zone").change(function(){
    var t =$("#zone").val();
    if(t==/*somevalue*/)
    {
        //set value for time id
        //like $("#time").val(/*new val*/)
    } 
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: take <value> and <text> as string viz "1","GMT 5.30" where 1 is id and GMT 5.30 is display name.

Comment: I whant to do this www.itorian.com/2013/04/populate-selected-item-in-dropdownlist.html but in this form seems not to be working.

Comment: want to add them dynamically.if yes, you have to use ajax and partialview for this. and if no then somewhere small mistake done by you.

Answer (score 0):

As I am using Time Zones I find cool solution that works only for time zones. First I actualy don't need table with time zones saved, but simple in my View I call library of .Net timezones:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(o =>o.TimeZoneId, TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().Select(o => new SelectListItem{Text = o.DisplayName, Value = o.Id}))
```